# Why java creates error to cast a object as callable?

Tags: java, multithreading, completion-service

I am trying to run CompletionService to execute number of threads.Here is my code

```
CompletionService<ReadProcess_MongoDB> taskCompletionService;
    taskCompletionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<ReadProcess_MongoDB>(pool);

 Collection<Callable<ReadProcess_MongoDB>> list = new LinkedList<Callable<ReadProcess_MongoDB>>();
       list.add((Callable<ReadProcess_MongoDB>) new ReadProcess_MongoDB(0));
       list.add((Callable<ReadProcess_MongoDB>) new ReadProcess_MongoDB(1));
```

Java  shows runtime error at list.add.
Eror:-( cannot be cast to java.util.concurrent.Callable).

Comment: Does `ReadProcess_MongoDB` implements `Callable`?

Comment: yes.you can see in line Collection<Callable<ReadProcess_MongoDB>> list

Comment: Its not the same. Refer `chiastic-security` answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line

```
list.add((Callable<ReadProcess_MongoDB>) new ReadProcess_MongoDB(0));
```

you're trying to *cast* your `new ReadProcess_MongoDB(0)` as a `Callable<ReadProcess_MongoDB>`. If this fails, it's because your `ReadProcess_MongoDB` class isn't castable to `Callable<ReadProcess_MongoDB>`; and that can only be because you didn't implement `Callable<ReadProcess_MongoDB>` in that class.

Declare it as

```
public class ReadProcess_MongoDB implements Callable<ReadProcess_MongoDB> {
    //...
}
```

You will then need to ensure that your class implements the methods of the `Callable` interface. There's only one: the [`call()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html#call%28%29) method.

(Be clear in your own mind that this is really what you want, though. Are you sure you don't want it to implement `Callable<T>` for some other type `T`?)

Answer (score 0):

The java compiler says that the ReadProcess_MongoDB class is not a sub-class of the java.util.concurrent.Callable class.

- Is it another Callable class you meant ? in this case you should specify the full package name in your cast: *package*.Callable
- Otherwise, you may need to implement the Callable class/interface to use the ReadProcess_MongoDB object you create.